# React.js Upload Files to server

Tags: reactjs, laravel-8, react-dropzone

I am trying to learn to **React** with Laravel 8 with Sanctum Authentication. I am trying to upload files to the server using `React`. I am using `react-dropzone` to drag and preview Images and Laravel8 Here's the react-dropzone code.

```
const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({
    accept: "image/*",
    onDrop: (acceptedFiles) => {
      setFiles(
        acceptedFiles.map((file) =>
          Object.assign(file, {
            preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
          })
        )
      );
    },
  });
```

I am getting files and it's preview. Here's the upload code which I am using to upload to the server.

```
const data = new FormData();
files.map((file) => data.append("images", file));
apiClient.get("sanctum/csrf-cookie").then(() => {
      apiClient
        .post("api/upload/image/1", data, {
          headers,
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.dir(err);
          toast.error("Something Went Wrong");
        })
})
```

On Laravel I am trying to capture request by
`$request->all()`
but it returns
 `images: {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture it by `file` function or as an object property e.g. `->images` instead of `all`.

More: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#files

Comment: I am trying to upload multiple images. how to capture all like in an array

Comment: @HamzaAfzal loop over it’s value.

Comment: I forgot to add [] with images